# Avoiding macros for near identical class definitions

Tags: c++

I have a base class for exceptions:

```
class BaseException : public std::runtime_error
{
public:

    BaseException(int Code, std::string Msg) : runtime_error(Msg);

    //...etc
};
```

In every class that needs exceptions, I embed a `Exception` class that inherits from `BaseException`:

```
class Foo
{
public:

    class Exception : public BaseException
    {
    public:

        Exception(int Code, std::string OptMsg = "") : BaseException(Code, OptMsg);

        enum
        {
            Fire,
            Flood,
            Aliens
        };
    };

    //...etc
};
```

So now I can `throw(Exception::Fire)` inside `Foo` and catch by base class or by `Foo::Exception&` and compare to `Foo::Exception::Fire` for example.

The `Exception` class definition is nearly identical every time tough, only the enum contents change. Because of DRY, I was thinking of writing a macro that allows something like this:

```
EXCEPTIONS
Fire,
Flood,
Aliens
END_EXCEPTIONS
```

However, macro's are frowned upon in C++. Is there a better way?

Comment: What's the enum for, and how is it related to the constructor arguments?

Comment: The enum describes the exception when throwing/catching, added this information to the question.

Comment: I think that's a design problem, then. The information about what kind of exceptional situation has arisen is divided between *type* and *data*. This seems inconsistent, and it is not type-safe, because you can pass any `int` to the constructor and not just valid enum values. If I were you, I'd go for a much simpler approach, eliminating either the status code or the `BaseException` subclasses.

Comment: My gut feeling is that having embedded Exception sub classes is not a good design. The reason is that calling/catching code will typically not know which particular object of which type/class has thrown; the catching code typically wants to know what *category* of error happened (invalid argument, resource acquisition failed, internal error etc.) and handle it differently depending on the type of error. It cannot do that with your design since all it knows is that it has some `BaseException`; the error codes of the various subclasses are numerically identical so it cannot even use those!

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider : `Foo::Exception` and `Bar::Exception` are different types, caught in a different catch block, the error codes can be used that way.

Comment: We frown upon macro's not because of a dogma, but because we have better alternatives. If you come from C, you probably should know how to convert the common uses of C macro's. Function-like? C++ has `inline`. Constant-like? C++ has `const.` Type-generic? C++ has `template`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can "inherit" the `BaseException` constructors with the `using` keyword instead of manually reimplementing them. This should save you some typing. The rest of the boilerplate is pretty minimal, so I personally wouldn't worry about it.

```
struct Foo {
  struct Exception : BaseException {
    using BaseException::BaseException;
    enum {
      Fire,
      Flood,
      Aliens
    };
  };
};
```

Comment: If you turn it into a `struct`, then you may as well remove the `public` from the base class specifier.

Comment: I missed that. I only turned it into a struct for brevity though.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
template <typename T>
struct Exception : BaseException
{
     Exception(int Code, std::string OptMsg = "") : BaseException(Code, OptMsg);
};

class Foo
{
public:

    using Exception = ::Exception<Foo>;    
    enum ExceptionCodes
    {
        Fire,
        Flood,
        Aliens
    };

    //...etc
};
```

(above unseen by a compiler)

The only difference is that you have to refer to `Foo::Fire` or `Foo::ExceptionCodes::Fire`.

You could do without the `using` statement, and just refer to `Exception<Foo>`.

Comment: *"above unseen by a compiler"* - Which is why one should not be surprised when the using statement will result in an error. Did you by any chance forget a `=`?

Comment: @StoryTeller: And a scope operator, I think. Inside Foo, attempting to look up unqualified `Exception<Foo>` would find `Foo::Exception`, making it a circular definition in addition to `Foo::Exception` not being a template.

Comment: @StoryTeller Sigh.  I should have known better than to use `using`, and stuck to good old `typedef`.

Comment: @MSalters I never can work out the rules for when names ignore the newly defined name, and when they don't - thanks for the fix.